# Verify an empty case with ngif

Tags: angular

I am facing something an issue that I'am not sure if I could make it this way. I would like to get a nested ngIf depending from a Json key.
 If they key exists show the black img and write the object in the key to the view, if the Json key doesn't exist write nothing(logic) and show the grey img.. the code will explain it better I guess:

```
    <div *ngFor="let user of userService.users | async">
           <div *ngIf="user?.data.apps.?tag as myEmpytag">
               <img *ngIf="myEmptytag === empty(so the Json key doesn't exist)" src="greyTag.png"/>
           </div>
           <div *ngIf="user?.data.apps.?tag as myFulltag">
              <div *ngIf="myFulltag === 'something is write(so the Json key is there)">
                <span class="tag3" *ngFor="let user4 of userService4.users4 | async">{{user4.data.incidents[2].tag}}</span>
                <img src="blacktag.png"/>
             </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: `user?.data.apps.tag` should evaluate to `false` if `tag` doesn’t exist, have you checked it?

Comment: @gsc Such a good idea but how could I evaluate the whole expression "user?.data.apps.tag" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is too many *ngIf in your code. You only need one *ngIf with a else template to do what you are looking for. Simply checking with `!user.data.apps.tag` should be more than enough. If the value is null, undefined, 0 or "", the negative assertion will be true.

```
<div *ngFor="let user of userService.users | async">
    <img *ngIf="!user.data.apps.tag; else elseBlock" src="greyTag.png"/>
    <ng-template #elseBlock>
        <span class="tag3" *ngFor="let user4 of userService4.users4 | async">{{user4.data.incidents[2].tag}}</span>
        <img src="blacktag.png"/>
    </ng-template>
</div>
```

If you need to make a more complex `if` statement, then create a function in your component and call it in your `*ngIf` to handle the assertion to avoid convoluted HTML.

```
*ngIf="myAssertFunction(user)"
```